# Mouse Control, I am looking to have a pictureBox follow the mouse cursor at a certain rate

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mouseevent, mouselistener

A bit lost here with first time accessing cursor's properties for movement.
I want a pictureBox(player) to move slowly towards the mouse cursor after fst_click(bool) is enabled. I have tried a multitude of methods but have had no success. I have tried cases but my return methods are inoperable any help on this?

I though maybe a mouse listener of some sort, to update the location of the mouse and depending on timer speed move towards the location but paths are definitely not my strong point.

```
private int _x;
    private int _y;
    private bool MRight = false;
    private bool MLeft = false;
    private bool MUp = false;
    private bool MDown = false;
    bool fst_click = false;
    private Position _objPosition;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clicking = true;
    }
    public void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        { clicking = true; }
    }
```

***I removed the incorrect case statement and added a different bool. This statement did switch between  4 cases W, A, S, D but the player location couldn't be updated smoothly?***
***I also added a timer to attempt to insert a boolean that would create        smooth movement but again I couldn't relate to the players' location?***

```
public void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clicking == true)
        {
            player.Location = Cursor.Position;
            clicking = false;
        }
     }

    private void Form1_MouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Point mousePoint = new Point(player.Location.X, player.Location.Y);
    }
```

**Update**
I have added the new coding below, if there are any ideas on how to repair this as I get no functionality from it. The cursor needs to be moving towards the clicked position at a certain speed, the commented out code is a failed attempt and I am looking to replace it.

```
namespace games1
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
            tmrMoving.Enabled = true;
            Invalidate();
     }
    private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var xdiff = Cursor.Position.X - player.Location.X;
            var ydiff = Cursor.Position.Y - player.Location.Y; 
            var diff = Math.Sqrt(xdiff + ydiff);

           //    diff = ydiff / 10;
           //    diff = xdiff / 10;

           // xdiff = player.Location.X;
           // ydiff = player.Location.Y;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't move to the cursor position, move incrementally by the speed of the player.  Don't set *clicking* back to false unless the button is actually released.  Or the player arrived at the cursor position.  Set the Timer.Interval to a value like 15, 31, 46 so you can emulate a game loop with it.  Don't use a PictureBox, just use Graphics.DrawImage() in the container control's Paint event handler.  Call its Invalidate() method to get a repaint.

Comment: Can you Psuedo your comment into a Psuedo sentence please? Just a bit confused with your method; but it maybe just how I'm reading it?

Comment: Still need help here.

Comment: I am lost on your question. *...to move slowly towards the mouse cursor*, you have to define slow. *...after fst_click(bool) is enabled*, you dont even use `fst_click` in your code. Also in `tmrMoving_Tick` event you set the player location at the exact cursor position, but following your initial question you said to **follow**. You need to explain better what you want.

Comment: I am looking to move the 'player' to the mouse when the user clicks.

Comment: When the user click or mouse down? If the user drag the mouse what then? When does it stop? What speed?

Comment: The player moves to the clicked position at an editable speed. If mouse clicked again before use arrives then last position is replaced by new position.